# How to search for specific value in every field of Entity with complex types?

Tags: c#, linq

Like in the topic. I need to iterate through every property of entity and properties of complex types and check if its value is similar to given value. I made something like this but it's very inefficient and it takes like 1-2 seconds to find value in three records table. How to make is faster ? I tried rewrite it to linq but every attempt failed.

```
    private List<AddressBook> SearchContact(string searchText)
    {
        var ToReturn = new List<AddressBook>();
        using (var cntx = Model.DBService.Instance.CreateContext())
        {

            foreach (var s in cntx.AddressBooks.ToList())
            {
                Type AddressBookProperties = s.GetType();
                Type PersonInfoProperties = s.PersonInfo.GetType();
                Type AddressProperties = s.Address.GetType();
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in AddressBookProperties.GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (prop.GetValue(s).ToString().Contains(searchText))
                        {
                            ToReturn.Add(s);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in PersonInfoProperties.GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (prop.GetValue(s).ToString().Contains(searchText))
                        {
                            ToReturn.Add(s);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in AddressProperties.GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (prop.GetValue(s).ToString().Contains(searchText))
                        {
                            ToReturn.Add(s);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
        return ToReturn;
    }
```

Model:

```
public class AddressBook
{
    public AddressBook()
    {
        this.Address = new Address();
        this.PersonInfo = new PersonInfo();
    }
    [Key]
    public int AddressBookID { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }
    public String RecordName { get; set; }
    public Boolean isPerson { get; set; }
    public Boolean isFirm { get; set; }
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class PersonInfo
{
    private string fullName { get; set; }

    public string Fullname
    {
        get
        {
            if (fullName == null)
            {
                fullName = Firstname + " " + Surname;
                return Firstname + " " + Surname;
            }
            return fullName;
        }
        set
        {
            fullName = value;   
        }
    }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ExtField { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string NIP { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string FlatNumber { get; set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostOffice { get; set; }
    public string Commune { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }}
```

Comment: Your query is slow, because you're bringing all the data into your application and than iterate over it. Every iteration heavily uses Reflection, which is not really a fast thing. You'd have to create an expression tree to move the processing to the database.

Comment: Sounds like you want full text search http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch

Comment: This expression tree...how do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by building up a dynamic expression tree so that all processing gets done on the database. Here's some code to get you started:

```
private static IEnumerable<Expression> GetConditions(Expression instance, Expression searchTerm)
{
    // note: if you have properties like FullName that don't map directly
    // to database columns, you'll need to filter those out here
    var stringProperties = @object.Type.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    // GetMethod from 
    // http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/
    var containsMethod = Helpers.GetMethod((string s) => s.Contains(default(string)));

    // for each property, generate an expression 
    // instance.Prop.Contains(searchTerm)
    return stringProperties.Select(p => 
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(instance, p),
            containsMethod,
            searchTerm
        )
    );
}

// use the above method like so:
var bookParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AddressBook));
var personInfo = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
    bookParameter, 
    typeof(AddressBook).GetProperty("PersonInfo")
);
// ... create more for other complex types
var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);

var allConditions = GetConditions(bookParameter, searchTermExpression)
    .Concat(GetConditions(personInfo, searchTermExpression))
    // ... add conditions for other complex types

// combine the conditions into a single expression with OR:
// ab.RecordName.Contains(...) || ab.PersonInfo.Name.Contains(...)...
var combinedCondition = allConditions.Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);

// create a lambda which you can pass to Where()
// ab => ab.RecordName.Contains(...) || ab.PersonInfo.Name.Contains(...)...
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<AddressBook, bool>>(
    combinedCondition,
    bookParameter
);

// filter the query
var filtered = ctxt.AddressBooks.Where(lambda);
```